# alias script is not running `source ~/.bash_profile`

Tags: bash, shell, alias

I have modified my .bash_profile script with the following command:

```
alias shortcuts-update='nano ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile && say profile shortcuts have been updated'
```

It's a great way to add aliases on the fly.  The `nano` works well but the the `source ~/.bash_profile` does not!  I must run it manually before any changes I have saved in .bash_profile take effect.  Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: The second command will only execute if the first returns an exit code of 0 and so ensure that you are exiting nano correctly. If need be, run this step manually and then check the exit status through checking $?

Comment: I am not familiar with this process, can you provide me with an example command?

Comment: Run the nano command,from the command prompt and then when you have finished and return to the command line, echo $? and confirm that 0 is returned.

Comment: Well, I added ` && echo $? && ..` to my alias command and the `source` command worked.  Thanks.